# Interpolating column of first dataframe based on second dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, interpolation

Suppose that I have 2 dataframes `df1`:

```
col1
0
10
20
30
```

and `df2`:

```
col1     val
0        0
5        2
15       4
25       5
33       8
```

I want to compute `val` column for `df1` that is linearly interpolated from `val` in `df2` based on `col1`. Also note that `col1` in both dfs are sorted in strictly increasing order.

So `df1.val` should look as follows:

```
0 (no interpolation needed since there's an exact match on col1)
3 (interpolate between df2.iloc[1] and df2.iloc[2])
4.5 (interpolate between df2.iloc[2] and df2.iloc[3])
5 + 5 / 8 * 3 = 6.875 (interpolate between df2.iloc[3] and df2.iloc[4])
```

One idea I have is to use `merge_asof` twice and then interpolate.

```
df1["val_left"] = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2[['col1', 'val']],
                                on='col1',
                                direction='backward')["val"].values
df1["val_right"] = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2[['col1', 'val']],
                                on='col1',
                                direction='forward')["val"].values
# then do the interpolation in df1, but I don't have the df2.col1 info (is there an easy way to get that) to do the interpolation?
```

Are there (better) alternative approaches besides the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`numpy.interp`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html#numpy.interp) to create a 1D linear interpolation?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.interp(x=df1['col1'], xp=df2['col1'], fp=df2['val'])
array([0.   , 3.   , 4.5  , 6.875])
```

The function fits on `xp` & `fp`, and predicts on `x`.

Comment: This is really simple and elegant. Is there any overhead cost associated with using numpy functions on a pandas dataframe/series?

Comment: @roulette01 I don't know in detail, but I would expect not since pandas is built extensively on numpy.  Doing `%%timeit` on your `merge_asof` code (which still needs to do the interpolation) gives me `3.1 ms ± 48.8 µs per loop`, while creating a new column with `np.interp` gives me `82.5 µs ± 1.36 µs per loop`.